# Kubernetes Dashboard does not show CPU and Memory Usage

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard, metrics

I have a Problem with the Kubernetes Dashboard.
I use actually the Managed Kubernetes Service AKS and created a Kubernetes Cluster with following Setup:

- Kubernetes-Version 1.20.9
- 1 Worker Node with Size Standard_DS2_v2

It starts successfully with the automatic configuration of **coredns**, **corednsautoscaler**, **omsagent-rs**, **tunnelfront** and the **metrics-sever**.

After that i applied three deployments for my services, which all are deployed successfully.

Now, i want to get access to the Kubernetes Dashboard. I used the instruction which is described on https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/k8s-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard.

After that I call **kubectl proxy** to access the dashboard via the url: http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/.

After i use my kubeconfig-File to Sign to Kubernetes Dashboard i get following output and nor cpu neither memory usage is displayed.

[image]

When i execute kubectl describe kubernetes-dashboard pod i get following:
[image]

And the logs from the pod say following:

```
Internal error occurred: No metric client provided. Skipping metrics.
2021/12/11 19:23:04 [2021-12-11T19:23:04Z] Outcoming response to 127.0.0.1:43392 with 200 status code
2021/12/11 19:23:04 Internal error occurred: No metric client provided. Skipping metrics.
2021/12/11 19:23:04 [2021-12-11T19:23:04Z] Outcoming response to 127.0.0.1:43392 with 200 status code
2021/12/11 19:23:04 Internal error occurred: No metric client provided. Skipping metrics.
```

Comment: You also need to install [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server).

Comment: It is already installed when kubernetes cluster starts in AKS, The installed metrics-server on AKS is: 
mcr.microsoft.com/oss/kubernetes/metrics-server:v0.3.6

Comment: Can you verify it's working? If you have an HPA in your cluster, it will also show metric errors when you `describe` it if the metric server is not functioning properly

Comment: I have a HPA for a deployment. When i call kubectl describe hpa ... or when i call kubectl top nodes, i can see the metrics. I am wondering, why it outputs this error and the cpu and memory usage is not shown

Comment: Seems you now also need the dashboard metric scraper. This was not required last time I used k8s dashboard, but it looks like it's needed now: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/dashboard-metrics-scraper

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`... I used the instruction which is described on https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/k8s-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard.`

The dashboard needs a way to "cache" a small window of metrics collected from the metrics server. The instruction provided there doesn't have this enabled. You can run the following to install/upgrade kubernetes-dashboard with metrics scraper enabled:

```
helm upgrade -i kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard --name my-release \  
--set=service.externalPort=8080,resources.limits.cpu=200m,metricsScraper.enabled=true
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It helped me to solve the problem. I make following steps: 1) helm repo add kubernetes-dashboard https://kubernetes.github.io/dashboard/, 2) helm install my-release kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard --set=service.externalPort=8080,resources.limits.cpu=200m,metricsScraper.enabled=true, 3) pod-name=kubectl get pods -n default -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=kubernetes-dashboard,app.kubernetes.io/instance=my-release" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}" and 4) kubectl -n default port-forward "pod-name" 8443:8443 and now i can see the cpu and memory usage